# C# Programming Return ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am trying to return an error message for a method in my code, but I am unable to find the correct return object, I have searched on the internet but have no been successful in finding an answer.
The following is a code snippet:

```html
public ArrayList getBeneficiaryID(string UserID)
{
    try
    {
        //long Beneficiary_ID = 0;
        //string BeneficiaryID = "";
        ArrayList BeneficiaryArray = new ArrayList();
        // Open connection to the database
        string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Databasebcfintec_alice"].ConnectionString;
        aConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        aConn.Open();

        // Set up a command with the given query and associate
        // this with the current connection.
        string sql = "Select BeneficiaryID from Beneficiary where user_id = '" + UserID + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        cmd.Connection = aConn;

        // Execute the query
        odtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (odtr.Read())
        {
            BeneficiaryArray.Add(odtr["BeneficiaryID"]);
            //User_ID = (long)(odtr["user_id"]);
            //UserID = User_ID.ToString();
        }
        odtr.Close();
        return BeneficiaryArray;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
        //return ex.ToString();
        return;
    }
}
```

Error Message:

> "An object of a type convertible to arraylist is required"

---

Another method I tried was using the following code:
return ex.ToString();

but it provided the following error message:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.ArrayList'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put `return null;` or `return new ArrayList();`
 since it looks like you don't care with what you're gonna get with the catch. You already have a console log.

Comment: Thank you that helped, but I would like to know the proper way to return the error message for an ArrayList, do you happen to know the answer to that?

Comment: I'm not really sure what message to show. Just show the `Exception` message throught `Console.WriteLine`, it's helpful enough, so you don't have to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to return an object. You can't do

```
return;
```

because you're not returning anything. You also can't return a string because it can't be cast to an ArrayList.

You can, however, return null, which it sounds like is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In the catch section you should have to throw the exception.

```
public ArrayList MethodName(string UserID)
{
        try
        {
          //write your code
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            //log the exception
           throw ;
        }
}
```

Comment: That's not true, you don't necessarily have to throw an exception from the catch. That's only true if you don't know how to handle the exception there, in which case it's a better practice to re-throw it. Also, you should do `throw;`, not `throw ex;`.